# How to export a rendered table data to pdf file or any other format in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, render, html-to-pdf

I am working on to export the table data to pdf format using `Reactjs`. I am showing the `json data` in the form of a HTML table inside `Reactjs component`.

I have given a button named as `Export` to export the data in any format. For now I am working only to export the data to PDF Format. Can anyone help me with this. Is there any Package to import or any specific code to do to export the data to PDF file. Anything can be useful. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your dom to canvas and save the canvas as pdf,

DOM to canvas,

```
const input = document.getElementById('mytable');
html2canvas(input)
  .then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  })
;
```

Canvas to pdf,

```
html2canvas(input)
  .then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");  
  });
;
```

Refer https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-create-pdfs-from-react-components-client-side-solution-7f506d9dfa6d

As suggested ,

We can also use `jspdf-autotable` to generate pdf (works only with table or jsonarray),

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
    // You can use html:
    doc.autoTable({html: '#my-table'});

    // Or JavaScript:
    doc.autoTable({
        head: [['Name', 'Email', 'Country']],
        body: [
            ['David', 'david@example.com', 'Sweden'],
            ['Castille', 'castille@example.com', 'Norway'],
            // ...
        ]
    });

    doc.save('table.pdf');
```

Comment: Yes this is a good solution but does not works in my case. It shows only the data that is shown in that particular page. If I have a table that has multiple pages then how to show those multiple data in multiple pages on the pdf? can you help me using the above solution ?

Comment: You cant render a full table in pdf if it is paginated , I would suggest you to dynamically create a table and add all the rows and use it to create the pdf. .You can see in the same article to lean how to generate multiple pages pdf.

Comment: @SrinivasanSekar yeah we can create a table dynamically as suggested in the article that you shared, but I found another easy way to solve it by using "jspdf-autotable" package. In this we can pass the JSON Object that we are displaying in the HTML table. So by passing the whole JSON Object will help us to show the whole data in the PDF rather than showing only the active table page data.

Comment: pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0); what does both 0s stands for?

Answer (score 0):

Download the .zip file and check the demo file. then use it. link below.

[tableExport.jquery.plugin-master](https://idealthinkerprojects.com/lab/)

Comment: I downloaded it but could not find any demo fie which I can run. can you help me with this ?