# Export Pdf in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I have some tables on my pages, Above that, I have to give a dropdown where users can select either save the table in PDF or Excel Format.

The table is dynamically created where **Header is in array form** and **data is a nested array of object**.

Is there any best library that I can use to export to pdf and export to excel, my nested dynamic table?

Comment: You should check https://material-table.com/#/

Comment: Can't I make this with out without replacing my table which I have already made.

Comment: Yes you can. Check this https://hackernoon.com/how-to-export-html-tables-into-pdf-documents-using-javascript-1z223wnq

Comment: This might help as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215365/1930155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the solution the this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989119/generating-a-pdf-file-from-react-components) using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) & [JSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) or install the library [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/) and use it in your project.